# Limiting a query to the 5 lowest values for a query to the 5 lowest values for a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to limit the query below to 5 results.  But not just any 5 results.  The 5 lowest values for `points`.  How can I do this?

```
$side = "SELECT title, points, submissionid
             FROM submission 
            WHERE points >= '$sidepoints' 
         ORDER BY points DESC";
```

**EDIT:**  I want the results ordered by `points` descending.

Comment: do you wish to view them in mysql or can you simply read them into a php array and reverse before printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to order your query result with another query (subquery)

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT title, points, submissionid
  FROM submission 
  WHERE points >= '$sidepoints' 
  ORDER BY points ASC
  LIMIT 5
) t ORDER BY t.points DESC
```

Comment: Elegant.  Short and sweet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In MySQL:

```
$side = "SELECT title, points, submissionid
         FROM submission 
         WHERE points >= '$sidepoints' 
         ORDER BY points ASC
         LIMIT 5";
```

**EDIT**

You can use the above query with the following PHP code or use a different SQL Query.

PHP Reverse results (untested)

```
$q = mysql_query($side);
$results = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $results[] = $r;
}
$results = array_reverse($results);
foreach($results as $result)
{
    echo $result['points']; // etc
}
```

Or the SQL way (untested as well - found from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301745/138383))

```sql
SELECT title, points, submissionid 
FROM (
    SELECT title, points, submissionid
         FROM submission 
         WHERE points >= '$sidepoints' 
         ORDER BY points ASC
         LIMIT 5
) AS t1 ORDER BY points DESC
```

Comment: Okay... but how do I get the results to display descending?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using MYSQL use `LIMIT`.

```
$side = "SELECT title, points, submissionid
         FROM submission 
         WHERE points >= '$sidepoints' 
         ORDER BY points DESC
         LIMIT 5";
```

The ansi sql uses `TOP`. This will work for sql server

```
 $side = "SELECT TOP 5 title, points, submissionid
             FROM submission 
             WHERE points >= '$sidepoints' 
             ORDER BY points DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT ... ORDER BY points ASC LIMIT 5 ?