# PHP: MYSQL QUERY Ordery By

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Image Table
[image]

Hello i have a table `comments` and i need to take the last three comments but another way like this:

```
8
9
10
```

My code show this:

```
10
9
8
```

Code:

```
$sql_query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE `post_id` = '38' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3");

while ($ff = $sql_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $ff["text"]. "</br>";
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Wrap your statement in a subquery and resort it, in ascending order, by comment ID.

Comment: Changing 'DESC' to 'ASC' will make it work i guess.

Comment: @Terry please show me the code

Comment: @Denisx noo not work

Comment: `ORDER BY text ASC` if that `ASC` doesn't work with the ordering by `text`, use `DESC`

Comment: @Fred-ii- with `LIMIT 3` that would return 1, 2 et 3 or 10, 9, 8 again. This requires a subquery or manual result array reversing.

Comment: @sidyll I can't see why `ASC` isn't working for them, as previously suggested.

Comment: @GAASD you have answers below, see those.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `order by text` would return (1,2,...,10) and with `limit` that becomes (1,2,3). With `desc`, (10,9,...1) becoming (10,9,8). He wants (8,9,10). The thing is, `limit` aways counts from the beginning of the set. To count from the end, a subquery is needed.

Comment: @sidyll Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you. The only other alternative I could think of is using `limit` with an offset, for example `order by text limit 3 offset 7` would work. This got me into thinking if we could build that offset number dynamically with a subquery. I'll post a question to the MySQL experts here.

Comment: @sidyll Funny you should mention about LIMIT's offset option. I had written a comment to the OP to that effect but deleted it. I should have left it in place. I guess I could ask a mod to undelete but feel it's not worth it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Interesting. In this particular case, I think the easiest way is to reverse the set with PHP but indeed if the count of rows is known limit with an offset is a super clean way of doing it. However I don't know if it is possible to count the rows as a subquery and use it as offset, all in one query. Just posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336890/) about that.

Comment: @sidyll doubly interesting comment there. I'll keep an eye out on your question, *cheers*

Comment: @GAASD mind telling me why you went and deleted your question that we were helping you with? http://stackoverflow.com/q/41371073/1415724 I have a good mind to flag to a moderator to get it undeleted. It's clear that we solved it for you. That wasn't right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a subquery, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301739/mysql-reverse-order-without-desc) question. However it might be easier to just use PHP's [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php):

```
$rows = array_reverse($sql_query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
foreach ($rows as $ff)
    echo $ff["text"]. "</br>";
```

With the subquery, if you wish:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM comments
  WHERE `post_id` = '38'
  ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3
) t ORDER BY t.id
```

Basically this creates a derived table aliased to `t` with the result of your original query, and reorders this limited set of results.

Comment: I'll have to remember about that `array_reverse()`. I've never used it before but might in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Following query will give your desider output

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE `post_id` = '38' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3) temp order by id
```