# PHP: When add GROUP BY i get error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Hello my code work perfect but when i add GROUP BY i get error, THANKS IN ADVANCE:

```
$sql_query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_to` = '1'");-Work perfect
$sql_query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_to` = '1' GROUP BY `sent_by`");- Not Work
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Code:

```
$sql_query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_to` = '1' GROUP BY `sent_by`");

if($sql_query->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($fetch_data = $sql_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo $fetch_data["text"]. "</br>";
    }
}
```

Table:[HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRTUq.png)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chat` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sent_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sent_to` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `text` text COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `seen` enum('0', '1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` is for aggregation, are you sure you're not looking for `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @Uueerdo no, i need grup by for same messages

Comment: I just created the table and did a query __SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_to` = '1' GROUP BY `sent_by`__

Comment: `GROUP BY sent_by` will effectively give you random values for all the fields (selected from the values seen with the sent_by value in the result row); it is meant for operations like COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, etc....

Comment: Yeah you will get meaningless results here. You'll get the first result sent by each person

Comment: @YounElan i try: SELECT * FROM chat WHERE sent_to = '1' GROUP BY sent_by

Comment: @GAASD I group by is for aggregation field - either with sum, max, avg - if you are having select * then as they mentioned you may have garbage but the query executes

Comment: What are you trying to do? if it just putting them together, you can have order by and split them at the client. If you are trying to get all messages in one string, then you may use **group_concat** can you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you do `SELECT text` you should be ok, since that is the only row you're echoing. As per a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371073/php-when-add-group-by-i-get-error-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object#comment69944072_41371126) I left under an answer also below.

Comment: did you manage to sort this out? Did my answer work?

Answer (score 3):

mysqli returns false on failure. Which means your group by query has failed. Which in turn implies that you are using [mysql 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and

> MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If
>   the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default),
>   MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or
>   ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in
>   the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before
>   5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of
>   pre-5.7.5 behavior, see the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.)

In other words the query you are trying is invalid SQL. Mysql allowed you to execute such queries until 5.7 but no longer. But you can still run it with the `ANY_VALUE` function or disabling `FULL_GROUP_BY`. However that would still make your query invalid SQL as pointed out by Fred.

The only real solution is for you to change your query. For example the following will work.

```
SELECT sent_by FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_to` = '1' GROUP BY `sent_by`
```

You are apparently trying to get the text column. So for an ANSI SQL compliant query you need a bit of work

```
SELECT a.sent_by, a.`text` FROM chat a INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sent_by FROM `chat` WHERE `sent_to` = '1' GROUP BY `sent_by`) AS B ON a.sent_by = b.sent_by and a.sent_to = 1
```

Comment: it's there in my answer. Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, use ANY_VALUE or change your query

Comment: @e4c5 Yeah, but that doc also states: *"For the query to be legal in SQL92, the name column must be omitted from the select list or named in the GROUP BY clause."* So, the `SELECT *` is the culprit here.

Comment: yes @Fred-ii- I will edit my answer to suggest that the user does that without juggling the settings.

Comment: @e4c5 OP is doing `$fetch_data["text"]` that column needs to be selected. Edit: op deleted, wtf??

Comment: yes @Fred-ii- I was about to reply to your comment and edit the post when the question was deleted. Now seems reopened. Not sure if worth the effort

Comment: @e4c5 That's because the OP deleted the question and I flagged the question to a mod to reopen. I think it was worth the effort and it being a good question.